# Deactivate time-limit in php.ini for cgi-php

Tags: php, cgi

What does this mean?

> deactivate time-limit in php.ini for cgi-php

1. What is `time-limit` in `php.ini`?
2. What is `cgi-php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is generally configured with a maximum executin time for any given script... if it exceeds this amount of time to process the script it dies with an error.

There are two primary ways to run php... as a module embedded within the server or as an interpreter utilized by a cgi module like [`fcgi`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI). You can have different php.ini configuration files for these different methods as well as the CLI interface you can use from a terminal.

So that this is telling you is to disable [`max_execution_time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) for the cgi configuration of php.

Comment: Ummm... what?:O So I should run my `PHP` as `CGI` with `fcgi` (is fcgi equals to `fastcgi`?), and how should I run `PHP` as `CGI`?

Comment: You could if you want... it depends on your requirements. Most hosting companies run it as CGI under shared hosting to give users more customization options, but it doesnt mean you have to.